# Compute median on filtered lines

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet with `category` and `value` columns.

I can use the `averageif()`, `minifs()` or `maxifs()` functions on a range to get the average/min/max of `value` for rows in a given `category`.

But is there a simple way to get the median of `value` for the rows in a given `category`?

Comment: What do you mean by lines?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I meant rows

Answer (score 0):

The [MEDIAN](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/MEDIAN) functions is available and:

> Returns the median of a set of numbers. In a set containing an uneven number of values, the median will be the number in the middle of the set and in a set containing an even number of values, it will be the mean of the two values in the middle of the set.

But, there is no `MEDIANIF` function (even Excel doesn't have it). You might to accomplish it by combining `MEDIAN` and `IF` functions.

Comment: I know the MEDIAN function, but I'm looking for an equivalent to a non-existent MEDIANIF function